# Merge 2 different lists as in the example

Tags: python-3.x, list

How can I combine the 2 lists below as in the example? len(list1+list2) = 5 but len(output)=2. Thank you for attention

```
 List1 = [array([12, 10, 8, 5, 7, 3]), 
          array([24,  58, 49, 30,70,6])]

 len(list1) = 2

 List2 = [array([63, 15, 72, 23,89,3]), 
          array([27,  60, 47, 29,57,6]), 
          array([47, 28, 50, 35,21,8])]

 len(list2) = 3
```

Example :

```
  Output = [ 
        [[12, 10, 8, 5, 7, 3], [24,  58, 49, 30,70,6]],
        [[63, 15, 72, 23,89,3],[27,  60, 47, 29,57,6],[47, 28, 50, 35,21,8]]
       ]

 len(output) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `append` command.

```
Output = []
Output.append(List1)
Output.append(List2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got two is because there are two elements in the list(two lists).

If have a list you can use the extend method to add a list like this:

```
    lis1 = [34,32,12]
    lis2 = [56,21,54]
    lis1.extend(lis2)
    print(lis1) # [34, 32, 12, 56, 21, 54]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append each variable in the list to the new list

```
output = []
for i in range(len(list1):
    output.append(list1[i])
```

And than do it for the second list
If you’ll just do output.append(list1) than list 2
it will be the same as your first output the one with len = 2